# Dismiss self present view from itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a web view controller, suppose A

The weviewcontrollerA contain 2 button at top ButtonA and ButtonB

Now my question is

From Another ViewControllerX i load weviewcontrollerA by passing URL as parameter, to  load www.google.com in the webviewControllerA view.

for example :

```
-(IBAction)loadweviewcontrollerA
{
 weviewcontrollerA *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"weviewcontrollerA"];
     vc.urltoload=@"https://wwww.google.com";
     [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Now in webviewcontrollerA , i have to reload the same view again with below condition
1) Reloading the viewDidload (or present the same class again) is compulsory as i have to pass some Parameter in the uRL also as HTTPRequest with the weburl

2) how to dismiss webviewcontrollerA , and then suddenly load it again without user known it.

how i jump,below code work, but user see ViewControllerX and the it load again, how i skip that user not visible the ViewControllerX or it load so quickly without user notice

```
-(IBAction)ButtonA
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO
                                completion:^{
 weviewcontrollerA *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"weviewcontrollerA"];
     vc.urltoload=@"https://wwww.facebook.com";
   UIViewController *topvc=[self topMostController];
                                    [topvc presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
                                    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
                                }];





-(IBAction)ButtonG
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO
                                completion:^{
 weviewcontrollerA *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"weviewcontrollerA"];
     vc.urltoload=@"https://wwww.twitter.com";
      UIViewController *topvc=[self topMostController];
                                    [topvc presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
                                    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
                                }];



//----------- END OF MORE INFO POP UP VIEW---------------

- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

Comment: Why are you making it so complicated, just because you need to change parameters to same class & reload web view? you can get parameter from another controller by using the delegate or notification & reload your page without dismissing & reloading controller.

Comment: its not only change parameter but also changes a lot of encryption and decryption, i know simply load a change URL request in any button action.
Thats why i am asking question here!